# Pascal's Triangle Row Sequence

Tags: recursion, scheme, pascals-triangle

I'm currently working on finding the row sequences of Pascal's triangle. I wanted to input the row number and output the sequence of numbers in a list up until that row. For example, `(Pascal 4)` would give the result `(1 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 3 1)`.

I am trying to use an algorithm that I found. Here is the algorithm itself:

> V<sub>c</sub> = V<sub>c-1</sub> * ((r - c)/c)

*r* and *c* are supposed to be row and column, and V<sub>0</sub>=1. The algorithm can be specifically found on the wikipedia page in the section titled "Calculating and Individual Row or Diagonal."

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
(define pascal n)
  (cond((zero? n) '())
       ((positive? n) (* pascal (- n 1) (/ (- n c)c))))
```

I know that's hardly anything but I've been struggling a lot on trying to find scoping the function with a `let` or a `lambda` to incorporate column values. Additionally, I've also been struggling on the recursion. I don't really know how to establish the base case and how to get to the next step. Basically, I've been getting pretty lost everywhere. I know this isn't showing much, but any step in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using as a guide the [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Calculating_an_individual_row_or_diagonal_by_itself) in Wikipedia, this is a straightforward implementation of the algorithm for calculating a value in the Pascal Triangle given its row and column, as described in the link:

```
#lang racket

(define (pascal row column)
  (define (aux r c)
    (if (zero? c)
        1
        (* (/ (- r c) c)
           (aux r (sub1 c)))))
  (aux (add1 row) column))
```

For example, the following will return the first four rows of values, noticing that both rows and columns start with zero:

```
(pascal 0 0)

(pascal 1 0)
(pascal 1 1)

(pascal 2 0)
(pascal 2 1)
(pascal 2 2)

(pascal 3 0)
(pascal 3 1)
(pascal 3 2)
(pascal 3 3)
```

Now we need a procedure to stick together all the values up until the desired row; this works for Racket:

```
(define (pascal-up-to-row n)
  (for*/list ((i (in-range n))
              (j (in-range (add1 i))))
    (pascal i j)))
```

The result is as expected:

```
(pascal-up-to-row 4)
> '(1 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 3 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I discussed Pascal's Triangle at my [blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2011/12/06/pascals-triangle/).

In your question, the expression for Vc is just for one row. That translates to code like this:

```
(define (row r)
  (let loop ((c 1) (row (list 1)))
    (if (= r c)
        row
        (loop (+ c 1) (cons (* (car row) (- r c) (/ c)) row)))))
```

Then you just put together a bunch of rows to make the triangle:

```
(define (rows r)
  (let loop ((r r) (rows (list)))
    (if (zero? r)
        rows
        (loop (- r 1) (append (row r) rows)))))
```

And here's the output:

```
> (rows 4)
(1 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 3 1)
```

The base case is `(= r c)` in the first function and `(zero? r)` in the second.

If you want to write subscripts clearly, you can adopt the notation used by TeX: subscripts are introduced by an underscore and superscripts by a caret, with braces around anything bigger than one character. Thus Vc in your notation would be V_c, and Vc-1 in your notation would be V_{c-1}.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!
So the first function has c acting as a counter. The let loop sets c to 1 and c will add 1 each time until r and c are equal in which row will be returned. I can see how the algorithm is implemented as well. The one part that I'm unsure of is row(list 1). So that makes '(1). After row passes (car row), does that mean we now have an empty set though? That element, 1, now is multiplied with (- r 1) (/c). My understanding is that cons is supposed to combine element and list. I see the element. But is the list supposed to be row in the back?

Comment: On the last row of the function, the cons puts the new element, which it calculates using the formula from WikiPedia, at the head of the existing row. For instance, when called as (row 4), variable row is initially (1), then the first time through the loop it becomes (3 1) and c becomes 2, then the second time through the loop row becomes (3 3 1) and c becomes 3, then the third time through the loop row becomes (1 3 3 1) and c becomes 4, then the fourth time through the loop r and c are both 4 so the function returns the current value of row, which is (1 3 3 1).